# C# открытие двери ИИ (Unity3D)

Tags: c#, unity3d, искусственный-интеллект

Такая проблема,  делаю игру на Unity ,  игра хоррор и в ней есть ИИ,  который ищет игрока по всему дому.  Еще в игре есть двери. Как сделать так, чтобы ИИ мог открывать двери, притом только стоящие перед ним?

Comment: Raycast кидать не?

Answer (score 2):

Самый галимый и простой в реализации способ - использовать триггер. Делаете колайдер-капсулу, размером больше чем NPС, ставите на ней параметр "IsTrigger", создаёте тэг "ДВЕРЬ" и делаете скрипт в котором пишем:

`public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.transform.tag == ("ДВЕРЬ")) (Метод для открытия двери);
    }`

Comment: Так же можно заставить NPC закрывать двери за собой, используя `protected virtual void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {if (other.transform.tag == ("ДВЕРЬ")) (Метод для закрытия двери);}`